# Replace very small numbers by zero in the expression

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

When I calculate derivative of expression  which is  function of x,y really small number appear in my answer.

Is there any way to omit them from expression.

Also my derivative is function of x,y assume my expression like below:

$x^2 +x y + 10^-30  x^2  y + y^2$

How can I to make zero $10^-30$?

Comment: You want [`Chop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html)

Comment: And `N`, i.e., `Chop@N@(x^2 + x y + 10^-30 x^2 y + y^2)`

Comment: really thanks for u help

Comment: I would be careful applying `N` to symbolic expressions.  `Power` has special handling that shields exponents from `N` but other exact values may be converted undesirably.  I propose something like this:  `x^2 + x y + 10^-30 x^2 y + y^2 /. {z_ /; Chop@N@z == 0 -> 0}`

Comment: Note that if `x=y` is large, that term with a small coefficient will dominate.

Comment: Also is there any way we define precision in  code?